# How does Blender convert driver output to rotational channels?

Tags: drivers

I have always assumed that the output of a driver will always be interpret radians as the units, when adding it to a rotational channel. However, this does not seem to be the case with my current project.

I have added a driver to the rotation channel of a bone, and it seems that the output of the driver is not matching the rotation channel. Moreover, it seems to be inconsistent, in the sense that it works for only certain output values.

[image: Output corresponding to 60 degrees works]

For instance, in the picture above, I have the driver output 1.047 (approximately pi/3), which gives me 60 degrees, as I intend it to. However, when I have the driver output 0.524 (approximately pi/6), it gives me 56.347 degrees; I expect it to be 30 degrees. The picture below shows this phenomenon.

[image: Output corresponding to 30 degrees does not work]

**Specifically, my question is:** Am I correct in assuming that drivers output into radians (in which case this a bug), or do I have the wrong idea of what is going on here?

**Additional Notes**: I have that pi/2 corresponds to 90, pi corresponds to 180, and even 0 corresponds to 0. However, pi/4 does not correspond to 45, nor does pi/6 to 30.

Comment: Yes it is definitely in radians. But what you see in the driver and in the UI might differ because of updating issues. It is very common Blender doesn't update stuff right. Try to force scene update and see if that fixes it. If you experience this there might be some dependency issues.

Comment: Darn! I wish it wouldn't have been that! Thank you very much.